# component doesn't works in the production

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that works fine when I use `npm start` but doesn't work when I build the project and use `npm run start:prod` the other components works fine
this a sceen of my component. I don't have any error in the console

[image]

I have the same error in same component when launch `npm run start:prod` in my static server where I deployed my react project

Comment: What is not working? What is the expected result? Is there any error in "network" tab?

Comment: the page not displayed it can be loaded